# removing elements from an array within an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

****************UPDATED*********************************************************

I have an array under an array: [image]

I want to remove an element from children array where type="tag" and name="style". children array is an array within the array of objects printed below.

My aim is also to keep the original array of objects intact.

[image]

I am using the following code but it is giving me undefined:

```
// ARRAY of Objects
const responseText = html.parse(businessResponseText);


console.log('responseText',responseText);

// Needs work ---- how do I transform this original object?
const transformedObject = {
...responseText, 
children: responseText.map((children)=>{
  children.children.filter(
    el => el.type !== "tag" && el.name !== "style" 
)
})
```

}

console.log('transformedobject',transformedObject);

this is the output I get: original vs transformed

[image]

Comment: Could you post readable examples rather than screenshots?

Comment: [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) returns `undefined`. Are you looking for [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const transformedList = styleFree.map(obj => ({
    ...obj, 
    children: obj.children.filter(
        el => el.type !== "tag" && el.name !== "style" 
    )
})
```

Comment: Hi can you re review the post? I need to change the children array within the array of objects

Comment: No problem!  Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Copy and paste the code snippet as it would be easy for others to try it. Make the world better place! ;)

```
stylefree = stylefree.map((children) => {
    children.children = children.children.filter((nested)=>{
        return (nested.type!="tag" && nested.name!="style");
    });
    return children;
});
```

Comment: I get back an array but the rest of the data is altered.

Comment: I need the original object intact with only the tag and style in children array gone

Comment: Do you just want to remove the "type" and "name" property from the nested children objects? Can you share the expected output?

Comment: I just want to remove the object from children array where type== tag and name==style

Comment: updating my original post.

Comment: I worked when I used Travis's answer. Thank you for your time :)