# Is it possible to do reduce instead of filter and map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, reducers

I am changing a object twice from and array of objects such that in the first iteration I filter out a few objects and in the second I change each of the filtered objects using map. Can I use reducer or something better?

```
  const originalTree = html.parse(text);

  if (originalTree[0].type === 'text') {
    return text;
  }
  const result = originalTree
    .map((obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      children: obj.children.filter((el) => el.name !== 'style'),
    }))
    .map((obj) => ({
      ...obj,
      children: obj.children.map(function(child) {
        child.attrs = {};
        return child;
      }),
    }));

  return html.stringify(result);
}
```

Comment: You can always [use transducers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44198833/how-to-chain-map-and-filter-functions-in-the-correct-order/)

Comment: I don't think a reducer makes sense here, as a reducer accumulates everything to a single final value. It looks like you want to keep your array intact.

Comment: @CalIrvine you can reduce to a single...array. A mapping operation can be defined as `arr.reduce((result, item, index, array) => [...result, mappingFn(item, index, array)], [])`

Comment: Can you give a sample of your `originalTree` at each step, including desired output?

Comment: Wouldn't just chaining on the `obj.children` makes more sense than mapping twice on `originalTree`?

Comment: Yes this is the original question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59686302/removing-elements-from-an-array-within-an-array/59686410?noredirect=1#comment105532907_59686410

Comment: Just do `children: obj.children.filter(/* */).map(/* */)`.

Comment: @VLAZ True, but that seems more convoluted than just using a map, in this case.

Comment: Since this is tagged as React, is the data immutable here?

Comment: @CalIrvine it was an example. You could do a lot more - you could have logic to map *and* filter at the same time, for example. Or do other types of manipulations - fill in specific array indeces and producing sparse arrays instead of only dense ones like `map` would do. `reduce` simply gives you more control, how you use that is up to you. And indeed transducers take the concept of array iterators to another level - you get a *chainable* and *lazy* iteration that is efficient as it goes over the entire array once, even if you do 7 mappings and 5 filters. Transducers are build on `reduce`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a way to loop with one `originalTree.map()`, also simplifying your `children.filter().map()` chain to a [`children.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) call:

```
const result = originalTree.map(
  obj => ({
    ...obj,
    children: obj.children.flatMap(
      el => el.name !== 'style'
        ? [{ ...el, attrs: {} }]
        : []
    )
  })
);
```

If you would rather continue using `filter()` and `map()` separately on `obj.children`, I would suggest at least adding `attrs` immutably instead of modifying the existing references:

```
const result = originalTree.map(
  obj => ({
    ...obj,
    children: obj.children.filter(
      el => el.name !== 'style'
    ).map(
      child => ({ ...child, attrs: {} })
    )
  })
);
```

Comment: it's definitely more legible

Comment: Now that's quite a complete answer! :)